# What encoding does the Census use in TIGER data?

Tags: census

What encoding does the Census distribute TIGER data in? The example on page 88 of [PostGIS in Action, Second Edition](https://www.manning.com/books/postgis-in-action-second-edition) seems to indicate latin1.

```
shp2pgsql -s 4269 -g geom_4269 -I -W "latin1"
➥ "tl_2012_states" staging.tl_2012_states |
➥ psql -h localhost -p 5432 -d postgis_in_action -U postgres
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this FAQ](https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/tiger/char_encoding.html) entry,

- TIGER/Line Files and Shapefiles through 2014
- Cartographic Boundary Files – Shapefiles through 2014
- Partnership Shapefiles – through 2014

Were all delivered in ISO-8859-1 (latin1), and

- TIGER/Line Files and Shapefiles 2015*
- Cartographic Boundary Files – Shapefiles 2015*
- Partnership Shapefiles – 2015*

While 2015 and later is UTF-8.

Note:
*: This data and all future dates